# Ef core many 2 many mapping

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-5

I have a 3 way many to many relation like this:

```
table 1 skill
table 2 instructions
table 3 person
```

Now I need to have a way to set for a combination of skill and person a list of instructions. I was thinking of having 1 table that has this mapping SkillId, InstructionId and PersonId. I have tried to set it up with HasOne.Withmany.HasForeignKey but it' not working. I am getting an error

> The property or navigation 'Instruction' cannot be added to the entity type 'PersonSkillInstruction' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'PersonSkillInstruction'

If I set up only the primary keys and let .netcore 5.0 do the trick for me I am getting another error

> The property 'PersonSkillInstruction.Instruction' is of type 'InstructionEntity' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

I know I could do something like create a many to many for person and skill and set an id then use that in a combination with instruction, but it feels very fishy.

How can I make this 3 way many to many work?

I am using .netcore 5.0, ef core, code first and sqlserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right thing to do is what you said:

> I know I could do something like create a many to many for person and
> skill and set an id then use that in a combination with instruction

Nevertheless, here you have an example if you want to create PersonSkillInstruction table.

```
public class PersonSkillInstruction
{ 
  [ForeignKey("person")]    
  public int PersonId { get; set; }        
  [ForeignKey("skill")]    
  public int SkillId { get; set; }    
  [ForeignKey("instructions")]    
  public int InstructionId { get; set; }    
  public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
  public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
  public virtual Instruction Instruction { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to set the PK in DBContext as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
// ...
  modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSkillInstruction>()
    .HasKey(t => new { t.PersonId, t.SkillId, t.InstructionId });
// ...
```

After adding a new migration, you have to reference two actions like this to avoid cycles:

```
// ...
  onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict
// ...
```

If this table will have heavy querying I suggest to use a surrogate key with a unique index like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSkillInstruction>()
  .HasIndex(t => new { t.PersonId, t.SkillId, t.InstructionId })
  .IsUnique();
```

[Link about surrogate key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50709/242898)